# In OpenLayers why is calculateExtent zoomed out

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers

I am trying to capture the extent of my Map on 'moveend' and it seems that the extent that is being captured is zoomed out quite a bit...

```
idle(event) {
function onMoveEnd(evt) {
const mapChange = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
}
MapValues.map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
}
```

I believe this is pretty much what I have seen as examples but it doesn't save the true zoomed extent on moveend.

Any help (especially the right solution :) ) is appreciated!

Comment: Are you expecting true distance on the ground?  You may need to adjust for point resolution https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.getPointResolution (e.g. Greenland may look as big as Africa on your map but it is not).

Comment: I'm not sure...but I don't think so.  I have an extent at the end of panning or zooming using the code above...but if I reload that extent it is not what I was previously looking at...it is zoomed out?

Comment: That will happen in versions 3, 4 and 5 (not 6) 
 Unless you specify `constrainResolution: false` in the options it goes to an integer zoom level https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what worked for me was adding this line after "calculateExtent"

```
 map.view.setResolution(map.view.getResolution() * 0.5);
```